# Mesclar imagem e mapa Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Tenho a seguinte situação. O mapa do google e acima do mapa adicionei uma imagem. O problema  que quando adiciono um evento no mapa, esse evento não funciona da imagem.. e vice e versa.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(historicalOverlay, "click", function(event) {
```

Como faço para adicionar esse evento em todo o mapa.

Mas tem um detalhe, é um """plugin""", então tenho medo de fazer alterações:
http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/

Será que é possível, eu adicionar a imagem atrás do MAPA, e dar uma opacidade no mapa...  Assim o mapa ficaria na frente, e o click funcionaria...  ou então, mesclar tudo, sendo a imagem e o mapa um só.

ATT

Answer (score 2):

o que voce pode fazer é ter uma div com a imagem de bg e o mapa dentro da div, e na div vc colocar uma função onclick. Para o usuário entender que é "clicável", voce pode colocar o css cursor:pointer na div. creio que seja isso que voce precise.

```
<div id="tudo" style="cursor:pointer; background: url(../image/bg.png) top center no-repeat #FFF;">
     <map></map>
 </div>
```

no caso, poderia ajustar a div e sua imagem de acordo com a necessidade.
  Caso necessite deixar o mapa transparente, para nao mexer no componente, pode colocá-lo dentro de outra div com opacity de 1 a 0.01.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas achei mais interessante utilizar este: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools